# Android studio unit test : Issues in writing mock tests for volley request (finished with non-zero exit value 1)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-volley

I have been trying to work on writing test cases for volley custom request, referencing For which I have implemented `FakeHttpStack` class and `FakeRequestQueue`from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618509/unit-testing-with-android-volley)

My project test class structure is as below :

```
/app
  /src      
  /test
     /java/package/myClassTest.java
     /resources/testfile.txt
```

`Gradle file`:

> ```
>  android {
>     compileSdkVersion 23
>     buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
>     defaultConfig {        
>         minSdkVersion 17
>         targetSdkVersion 23
>         // Enabling multidex support.
>         multiDexEnabled true
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
>         }
>     }
> }
> repositories {
>     maven { url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
>     jcenter()
> }
> dependencies {
>     compile project(':datetimepickerlibrary')
>     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
>     compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
>     compile files('libs/ksoap2.jar')
>     compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
>     compile files('libs/volley.jar')
>     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
>     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
>     testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
>     testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:3.0'
>     testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-maps:3.0'
>     testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
>     compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
> }
> task copyResDirectoryToClasses(type: Copy){
>     from "${projectDir}/src/test/res"
>     into "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/test/debug/res"
> }
> assembleDebug.dependsOn(copyResDirectoryToClasses)
> ```

My classes are as below:

`FakeHttpStack.java`

> ```
> import android.content.Context;
> import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
> import com.android.volley.Request;
> import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack;
> import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
> import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
> import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
> import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;
> import org.apache.http.Header;
> import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
> import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
> import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
> import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
> import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
> import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
> import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.InputStream;
> import java.io.InputStreamReader;
> import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
> import java.net.URL;
> import java.text.DateFormat;
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.Date;
> import java.util.List;
> import java.util.Map;
> public class FakeHttpStack implements HttpStack {
>    private static final int SIMULATED_DELAY_MS = 500;
>    private final Context context;
>    FakeHttpStack(Context context) {
>     this.context = context;
>    }
>    @Override
>    public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> stringStringMap) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
>        try {
>         Thread.sleep(SIMULATED_DELAY_MS);
>        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
>        HttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(new BasicStatusLine(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, 200, "OK"));
>        List<Header> headers = defaultHeaders();
>        response.setHeaders(headers.toArray(new Header[0]));
>        //response.setLocale(Locale.JAPAN);
>        response.setEntity(createEntity(request));
>        return response;
>     }
>     private List<Header> defaultHeaders() {
>        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd mmm yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
>        return Lists.<Header>newArrayList(
>             new BasicHeader("Date", dateFormat.format(new Date())),
>             new BasicHeader("Server",
>                     /* To use the appropriate server information that came back from Sakura server */
>                     "Apache/1.3.42 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8e")
>        );
>     }
>     private HttpEntity createEntity(Request request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
>         File file = getFileFromPath(this, "res/testfile.txt");
>         String resourceName = file.toString();
>         System.out.println("resourceName found " +resourceName);        
>         if (!file.exists()) {
>            System.out.println("No fake file named " + resourceName + " default fake response should be used.");
>         } else {
>            System.out.println("resourceName found " +file.getName());
>            try {
>             InputStream stream = context.openFileInput(resourceName);
>             String string = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(stream, Charsets.UTF_8));
>             if ("randomInt".equals(string)) {
>                 string = Integer.toString((int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE));
>             }
>             return new StringEntity(string);
>            } catch (IOException e) {
>               System.out.println("error reading " + resourceName + e);
>             }
>         }
>         // Since there is no appropriate resources, it returns appropriately
>         if (request instanceof StringRequest) {
>             return new StringEntity("100");
>         }  
>         return new StringEntity(" {\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3,\"d\":4,\"e\":5}");
>     }
>     private static File getFileFromPath(Object obj, String fileName) {
>        ClassLoader classLoader = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
>        URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
>        return new File(resource.getPath());
>     }
> }
> ```

`FakeRequestQueue.java`

> ```
> import android.content.Context;
> import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
> import com.android.volley.Cache;
> import com.android.volley.Request;
> import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
> import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
> import com.android.volley.toolbox.NoCache;
> public  class  FakeRequestQueue  extends  RequestQueue {
>     public  FakeRequestQueue (Context context) {
>         super(new NoCache(), new BasicNetwork(new FakeHttpStack(context)));
>         start();
>     }
>     @Override
>     public  void  start () {
>         System.out.println("request start");
>         super.start();
>     }
>     @Override
>     public  void  stop () {
>         System.out.println("request stop");
>         super.stop();
>     }
>     @Override
>     public  Cache  getCache () {
>         System.out.println("request start");
>         return super.getCache();
>     }
>     @Override
>     public  void  cancelAll (RequestFilter filter) {
>         System.out.println("Request cancel with filter " + filter);
>         super.cancelAll(filter);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public  void  cancelAll (Object tag) {
>         System.out.println("Request cancel with tag " + tag);
>         super.cancelAll(tag);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public  Request  add (Request request) {
>         System.out.println("Note: FakeRequestQueue is used");
>         System.out.println("New request "+ request.getUrl()+ " is added with priority "+ request.getPriority());
>         try {
>             if (request.getBody() == null) {
>                 System.out.println("body is null");
>             } else {
>                 System.out.println("Body:" + new String(request.getBody()));
>             }
>         } catch (AuthFailureError e) {
>             // cannot do anything
>         }
>         return super.add(request);
>     }
> }
> ```

`myClassTest.java`

> ```
>   public class OppTestCase {
>     private static FakeRequestQueue fakeRequestQueue;
>     @Before
>     public void setup() {
>         System.out.println("setup ");
>         if (fakeRequestQueue == null) {
>             fakeRequestQueue = new FakeRequestQueue(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext());
>         }
>     }
>     @Test
>     public void testinglist(){
>         GsonRequest<Result> gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<Result>(
>                 Request.Method.GET,
>                 Constants.STR_URL_LIST,
>                 Result.class,
>                 null,
>                 new Response.Listener<OpportunityListResult>() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onResponse(OpportunityListResult response) {                       
>                         System.out.println("response:"+response.toString());
>                     }
>                 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
>                         assertEquals(volleyError,notNullValue());
>                     }
>                 })
>         };
>         fakeRequestQueue.add(gsonRequest);
> }
> ```
>
> My **problem** is on running the test class it is always giving me error

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task '::dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1.
```

I am new in Android studio and writing test classes please guide where I am going wrong.

Comment: try running `./gradlew dexDebug --debug` to get more information as to why it is failing

Comment: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spaceError:Execution failed for task '::dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3 @hoomi

Comment: I think @Android Weblineindia answer seems to be correct one

Comment: Does this sort of testing test your code, or volley as a framework?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen for many reasons like due to not having enough RAM to build your project, so free up enough memory and if it does not solve your issue then you can try to remove unused dependency libs and sync your gradle, you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

Answer (score 0):

In the app-level build.gradle file, add

```
defaultConfig{
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```