# How to test Volley Library within Android studio?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-volley

I want to use the Volley Library to comunicate JSON file from an Android application to a REST API server. First of all I want to test the library with JUnit Tests, to see if my request are correctly sent, without run them within the application. Here is my test:

```
public class NetworkCommunicationTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    private static final String JSON_URL = "https://www.example.com/data.json";
    Context context;

    @Test
    public void testSendGet() {

        context = new MockContext();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             Assert.assertTrue("",true);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}
```

I've added this [library](https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin) into the Android Studio project, but I got this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:48)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
at tests.NetworkCommunicationTest.testSendPost(NetworkCommunicationTest.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

How Can I do to solve this problem? How Can I print the response.toString() message?

Just for more additional references, without the library I linked, I got isLoggable problem.

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: thank you for your reply, but the problem it's how to use in the Android, but how to use in a test in Android studio.

Comment: I was able to do the trick using FakeHttpStack described in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618509/unit-testing-with-android-volley