# Android, Espresso: Best tool for http STUB response

Tags: android

I'm using Android Volley for http request/response.

```
com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0
```

I write my Android instrumented unit test in folder "androidTest".

I test my logic and UI by JUnit and Espresso. And all work fine.

One of my Espresso test:

```
@Test
public void addFavorite() {
    onView(withId(android.support.design.R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText(CONTACT_SURNAME)).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
    onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.containerNotEmptyListView)).atPosition(0).onChildView(withText(R.string.add_favorites))
        .perform(click());
    onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.containerListView)).atPosition(0).onChildView(withText(R.string.remove_favorites))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

This Espresso test:

1. Scroll in listView to contact `CONTACT_SURNAME`
2. Click on item
3. As result start http request
4. After return PRODUCTION http response check is contact now has text "remove favorite"

This Espresso test work fine. OK!

Now I want to write unit test (also in folder "androidTest") that:

1. Check if success response (http status = 200) then show Toast
2. Check if incorrect response (e.g. http status = 403) then show Dialog

So, to do this I need some tool that return to me STUB http response.

I want this tool to must have the following options:

1. Write test directly from Android app (in folder androidTest).
   Something like this:

   ```
   @Test
   public void exactUrlOnly() {

          stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
                 .willReturn(aResponse()
                 .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                 .withBody("Hello world!")));
         assertThat(testClient.get("/some/thing").statusCode(), is(200));
         assertThat(testClient.get("/some/thing/else").statusCode(), is(403));
   }
   ```
2. This tool can return json in http response body.
   Something like this:

   ```
   {
       "response": {
           "status": 200,
           "body": "Hello world!",
           "headers": {
               "Content-Type": "text/plain"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Is anybody known such tool?
Thanks.

Comment: If You are using okhttp3 You can use for this the library com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver

Comment: I'm using Android Volley for http request/response.

Comment: you can check this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20297548/2067375 . That might help